# juju environment not found, can't bootstrap

Tags: 15.04, juju, amazon-ec2, aws

I installed juju onto Ubuntu 15.04 and have been using it for a few days. I managed to get it up and running with Amazon EC2 instances, which was fun.
I was trying again to start up a few instances on EC2 and the whole thing seemed to hang. Juju wasn't returning anything, and the instances hadn't start up in EC2.
However after I ctrl+c 'd the process, I now can't do anything with the Amazon environment. Trying to bootstrap:

```
brian@tonk:~$ juju bootstrap
WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/brian/.juju/environments/amazon.jenv"
WARNING This juju environment is already bootstrapped. If you want to start a new Juju environment, first run juju destroy-environment to clean up, or switch to an alternative environment.
ERROR environment is already bootstrapped
```

It says it already is bootstrapped. However, I can't destroy the bootstrap.

```
brian@tonk:~$ juju -v destroy-environment amazon
WARNING environment not found, removing config file environment not found, removing config file
```

So I tried removing the environment and ssh folders

```
brian@tonk:~$ rm -R .juju/environments
brian@tonk:~$ rm -R .juju/ssh
brian@tonk:~$ ls .juju/
environments.yaml  environments.yaml.backup  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  local
```

And try again to bootstrap:

```
brian@tonk:~$ juju bootstrap
WARNING This juju environment is already bootstrapped. If you want to start a new Juju environment, first run juju destroy-environment to clean up, or switch to an alternative environment.
ERROR environment is already bootstrapped
```

Still no joy. I then tried the status:

```
brian@tonk:~$ juju status
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "amazon".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
instances not found
```

So, I'm a bit stuck now. juju apparently is storing "something" ... "somewhere". 
Any idea where, so I can remove the reference, so I can start up AWS EC2 again. :)

Thanks in advance guys.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probabaly finding it in the s3 control bucket. Try this:

```
juju destroy-environment amazon --force
```

Comment: that was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

if manually deployed and as a last resort (Ubuntu1804, juju 2.6.8)

clean up the controller-node

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/juju

sudo rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/juju*

sudo rm -rf /run/systemd/units/invocation:juju*

sudo rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/juju*